# Indice tornando consulta sql muito lenta

Tags: sql-server, índices

o SGBD em questão é o SQL Server

No meu sistema, temos uma tabela que armazena os lançamentos contábeis. A tabela tem uma quantidade consideravel de registros, atualmente (em torno de 1.2milhoes).

Tem um índice clusterizado sobre um numerador sequencial, que é a chave primaria da tabela (sem regra de negocio, apenas um numero sequencial).

Tem uma coluna CodCliente. Recentemente foi criado um índice sobre ela, para usar em consultas filtrando por ela.

Porém, com isso, a consulta ficou extremamente lenta. Alguma coisa "errada" aconteceu.. com os dados já em memoria, a consulta levou 1 ou 2 segundos dropando o indice... e com o índice criado novamente, leva vários minutos!

A consulta ficou lenta em 2 usuarios que eu testei. Peguei um backup de um deles, e testei no meu ambiente, o mesmo comportamento foi identificado (ou seja: deve ser o índice realmente)

Detalhe: nessa consulta tem  "CodCliente not in (subconsulta)..."
Pelo fato de ter o índice, pode ter mudado tanto por causa disso?

Pode um indice deixar uma consulta mais lenta nesse caso?

A inserção na tabela, está normal, o unico problema foi que na demora da consulta, acabou bloqueando a tabela de contabilidade e deu timeout em muitos insert nela - muitos mesmo.

Consulta:

```
Select distinct CT.CodCliente,ct.codacesso FROM CT_Contabilidade CT  (nolock)
Inner join CD_PlanoContas PC ON CT.CodAcesso = PC.Cod  AND CT.CodPlano = PC.CodPlano 
WHERE (CT.CodCliente NOT IN (
    SELECT codcliente FROM ct_contabilidade SI (nolock)
    WHERE SI.CodPlano = CT.CodPlano And SI.codcliente > 0  And SI.CodAcesso = CT.CodAcesso And Year(SI.Data) = 2016
    AND month(SI.data) = 4 And ( SI.CodEmpresa = 1) )
    ) 
And CT.CodPlano = 1 AND MONTH(CT.Data) < 4 AND YEAR(CT.Data) = 2016 AND PC.subgrupo = 'C' 
And ( CT.CodEmpresa = 1 )  And ct.codCliente > 0
```

Abaixo vou colocar o plano de execução e as estatisticas de cliente geradas na execução quando EXISTE o índice:
(ia colocar, mas não pude colocar mais de 2 links p/ imagens. ficou apenas as estatisticas de cliente)

[image: consulta contabilidade - estatisticas do cliente]

E na sequencia, o plano de execução e estatísticas geradas pela execução da consulta quando NÃO TEM o índice (muito mais rapido):
(ia colocar, mas não pude colocar mais de 2 links p/ imagens. ficou apenas as estatisticas de cliente)

[image: consulta contabilidade - estatisticas do cliente (sem indice)]

Alguem pode dar alguma luz, o que pode ter acontecido?

Comment: Experimente algumas coisas.
1. Tente substituir o distinct pelo group by.
2. Procure não utilizar funções no filtro como MONTH() - Tente fazer com intervalo de datas. 
3. Veja se existe algum índice com os campos utilizados no Where.
4. Rode uma estatística do Banco.

Answer (score 1):

Como não foi informado todo o script de criação das tabelas irei partir para recomendações nas criações de índices e da consulta.

Em relação ao campo de `Data`:
As funções utilizadas no sob o campo faz com que o Engine do SQL ignore qualquer índice, então prefira o `between`

Join com a tabela `CD_PlanoContas`:
Não foi informado o tamanho da tabela, mas seria o caso de criar 2 indices
Um na própria tabela `CD_PlanoContas` com os campos (Cod, CodPlano) e o outro 
na `CT_Contabilidade` nos campos(CodAcesso, CodPlano)

Para a consulta em si:
No caso da consulta tenho 2 soluções

1 - criação de um indice na `CT_Contabilidade com os campos:
(SI.CodPlano, SI.codcliente, SI.CodAcesso, Data, CodEmpresa) include(codacesso)

2 - Remover a `subquery` e tranforma-la em um tabela temporária. O Script ficaria assim:

```
SELECT CodPlano,codcliente into #TMP FROM ct_contabilidade SI (nolock) WHERE SI.codcliente > 0  And Year(SI.Data) = 2016 AND month(SI.data) = 4 And ( SI.CodEmpresa = 1)

 Select distinct CT.CodCliente,ct.codacesso 
    FROM CT_Contabilidade CT  (nolock)
    Inner join CD_PlanoContas PC ON CT.CodAcesso = PC.Cod  AND CT.CodPlano = PC.CodPlano 
WHERE (CT.CodCliente NOT IN (
    SELECT codcliente FROM #TMP SI (nolock)
    WHERE SI.CodPlano = CT.CodPlano  And SI.CodAcesso = CT.CodAcesso )
    ) 
And CT.CodPlano = 1 AND MONTH(CT.Data) < 4 AND YEAR(CT.Data) = 2016 AND PC.subgrupo = 'C' 
And ( CT.CodEmpresa = 1 )  And ct.codCliente > 0
```

Veja qual das dicas você consegue aplicar e se há melhora